# After several days my Pi's stop being able to launch new processes nor allow SSH connections

Tags: raspbian, mono, crash

We are running raspbian stretch and have our mono based application running fine however we've found that after several days (this can be 2 days it could be 7) that our PI's just hang.

```
Kernel: Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SMP Tue Aug 8 16:00:15 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Our symptoms:

- The devices ping
- Unable to make SSH connections (it says enter login, but when you hit enter after your username it comes back with server disconnected
- We are unable to launch new processes via our UI

I've managed to get a dmesg on a device this morning which it has happened on and it shows:

```
mmc0: card never left busy state
mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD Card
EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): previous I/O error to duperblock detected
```

We are using Kingston Industrial SD Cards so I know the SD Cards are up to the task. Also, simply rebooting the devices brings them back to life

Can anyone advise further on what to look for?

[image: The actual dmesg screen]

Comment: That looks similar to the errors I was getting just before my SD card totally stopped working

Comment: FYI, it is always better to shut down a Pi from the command line (any computer for that matter).  When you say reboot, are you simply power-cycling the Pi?  If you are, doesn't matter how good the SDCard is - there will always be a chance you are corrupting it.

Comment: Of course if we have access to the system we always attempt a safe shutdown. The reboot im mentioning is we dont have access to the device and the user can only reboot them via a power cycle

Comment: cron a reboot at some nice time of the day...

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been up in several foryums since the dawn of the Raspberry Pi.

And culprit has been the SD card or the SD card holder.

And to troubleshoot:

- Reflash the SD card
- Try a different SD card brand.

**Note.** Never power cycle the Raspberry Pi, and by the way any OS it is the road to a corrupted file system.